# Error while passing the image to the AWS Rekognition

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

Getting an error of "**Request has invalid image format**" while getting the AWS Rekognition data using the amazon SDK with NodeJS. The image format is "JPEG" but still the code throwing an error.

The below codebase is working fine on my local instance. Getting an issue only on the AWS Amplify. The error is throwing inside the **client.detectLabels**  callback.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk') 
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')

const multer  = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.accessKey,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccess,
  region: process.env.region
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const bucketName = 'clear';
const storage = multer.memorystorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
  }

  const file = req.file
  const key = file.filename;
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file.path)

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key,
    Body: fileContent,
  };

  s3.upload(uploadParams, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error uploading image to S3:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to upload image' });
    } else {
      // Generate a pre-signed URL for the image
      const s3Params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: data.Key
      };

      s3.getObject(s3Params, (err, s3Response) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error retrieving image from S3:', err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to retrieve image' });
        } else {
          const photo = s3Response.Body
          const client = new AWS.Rekognition()
          const params = {
            Image: {
              Bytes: photo
            },
            MaxLabels: 10,
          };
          let labelObj = [];
          client.detectLabels(params, function (err, response) {

            if (err) {
              console.log(err, err.stack); // if an error occurred
              res.status(500).json({ error: 'AWS Rekognition callback having some issue', err, type: err.__type, message: err.Message, stack: err.stack, params, s3Params })
            } else {
              response.Labels.forEach((label) => {
                labelObj.push({
                  'label': label.Name,
                  'confidence': label.Confidence
                });
              });

              res.json(labelObj);
            }
          });
        }
      });
      
    }
  });
});
```